# Unknown symbol getting string from a file

Tags: php, laravel, file, utf

I'm using Laravel framework and I need to put a text inside a database field.
That's the code

```
    $files = \File::allFiles(base_path()."/public/TextDescription");
    $i = 0;
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $mmklisting = MMKL::whereMmkId(substr($file,47,-8))->first();
        if ( $mmklisting ) {
            $listing = Listing::whereMmkId($mmklisting->id)->first();
            if ( $listing ) {
                $text = mb_convert_encoding(substr(\File::get($file),2), 'UTF-16LE', "UTF-8");
                $text = str_replace("\r","",$text);
                $listing->save();
                $i++;
            }
        }
        \File::delete($file);
    }
```

but it store in the database an unknown symbol every char.
That's the result:

```
G���e���o���r���g���i���n���a��� ���l���o���v���e���s���
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: It's just a string to put inside a database field.

Comment: anybody know?..

Comment: Wow, did you delete my comment? Like, no humour allowed?

Comment: I didn't delete anything man, humour is always allowed